# I am not able to use equality in date query

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to compare a particular date in my SQL query in ORACLE BUT it is returning a null value. But if I am using greater than or less then it is working fine. Please check it and revert me with your feedback..

```
SELECT *   
FROM TICK 
WHERE stock_id = 7108 
  AND TRUNC(TICK_date) = To_date('30/08/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Returning a NULL value? Where? Do you mean an empty result?

Comment: yes it is returning a empty result

Comment: Then apparently there is no row with `stock_id=7108` ***AND*** `tick_date = '30/08/2013'`

Comment: Dear Sir my table contains record for that particular day

Comment: Thank u sir for ur help I got the point

Comment: Not, it does *not* contain a row for that *combination* of values - otherwise that row would have been returned.

Answer (score 0):

Returning null value means that there is no record which tick_date column is equivalent to To_date('30/08/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') after being truncated. What is your problem? I don't get it.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer